# Getting error when running "apt-get update" on docker image ubuntu:21.10

Tags: docker, 21.10

Running on WSL-2 and doing:

docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu:21.10

```
 root@72ad42cf1ee9:/# apt-get update
```

I get:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease [90.7 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease [270 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 Packages [620 B]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease [90.7 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease [90.7 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 Packages [16.7 MB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/restricted amd64 Packages [110 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/multiverse amd64 Packages [256 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 Packages [1793 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 Packages [620 B]
Fetched 19.4 MB in 22s (868 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Is anyone else seeing this? Any suggestions on how best to debug

Comment: How was the Docker container built? Usually they do not contain an entire OS because they’re meant to be either static for predictability, or ephemeral for scalability 

Comment: Is this a stack of Docker on Ubuntu on WSL? Or is this a stack of Ubuntu on Docker on Dockerd (or some other platform) on WSL?

Comment: If it helps, I just found out the docker repo does not yet support Ubuntu 21.10 / Impish.